# data migration from an embedded javaDB

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, derby, javadb

I am currently working on swign based javaSE application utlizing an embedded JavaDB for storing the data. My data model (and DB ) is fully java based utilizing JPA entities and JavaEE Persistence mechanism. No SQL scripts are used in the creation and management of the DB as everything is done by JPA.

As this application is going to be distributed to clients and clients usually require new features my question is if there is an effective way of getting the DB data and reinserting them after the updated application (with new tables, columns) has been delivered to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *dblook* (command line tool that comes with JavaDB) for an SQL dump of your JavaDB content and structure ([example here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheDerby/article.html#usage_sqldump)).

However, many structural db changes can be done with a non-empty database as well, e.g. adding columns or adding tables.